# "Quasiconformal" projections from Heisenberg group to the plane

Tags: quasiconformal, sub-riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be the 3-dimensional Heisenberg group equipped with its Carnot-Caratheodory subriemannian metric $d_{G}$. Let $U$ be a domain in $G$ of the form $V \times I$, where $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $I$ is an open interval (so $I$ is the third coordinate in $G$ corresponding to the center of the group). I'm going to consider uniformly continuous maps $f: U \rightarrow V$. Let $H$ be the left-invariant contact distribution on $G$.

Let $d_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}$ denote Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I want to consider a "quasiconformal" map $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ in the following sense: there is a constant $C \geq 1$ independent of $r$ such that for each $x \in U$, $y \in H_{x} \cap U$, 
$$
\frac{\sup\{d_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}(f(x),f(y)): d_{G}(x,y) =  r\}}{\inf\{d_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}(f(x),f(y)): d_{G}(x,y) = r\}} \leq C.
$$
In other words, for each $x \in U$ $f$ maps concentric circles in $H_{x}$ to quasiconformally distorted circles around $f(x)$. I want to conclude that if $A$ is a measurable subset of $V$ above with $m_{G}(A \times I) = 0$ ($m_{G}$ the Haar measure on $G$) then $m_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}(f(A \times I)) = 0$. So a form of transversal absolute continuity. Is this known?

What makes me think this is true is that, if we replace $G$ by $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the Euclidean distance with $H_{x}$ now being parallel planes orthogonal to the third coordinate, the conclusion follows from standard quasiconformal mapping theory on the plane + Fubini's theorem. Unfortunately this tactic does not work with $G$ because there is no foliation by transverse parallel planes.

Note: Overhauled an earlier version of this question that was nonsense.

Comment: What do you mean by $H_x \cap U$?  I would understand $H_x$ to be a subset of the tangent space $T_x G$, not a subset of $G$.

Comment: I'm imagining $G$ as $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $H_{x}$ represents the actual plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. But to make it precise without that identification with Euclidean space I think I'm considering $y \in \text{exp}(H_{x}) \cap U \subset G$.